# how do i compare two rows and store the similarities of the two rows in another column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

consider I have a table named table_1 as shown below

```
id               name          products_id
1                hi            1,2,3,4,5,6
2                hello         2,3,5,6
3                wow           5,6,9,10,13
4                total         1,2,5,6,9,13
```

now i want to compare id=1 and id=4 and make another column in the table which is having only the values in products_id that are similar in both the rows(that is id=1 and id=4).

so now how do i do it in MySQL and i want it the above process to happen for all the rows and the similarities should be stored in column 4 (that is the similarities column).

I want the final table to look like

```
id                name           products_id        similarity
1                 hi             1,2,3,4,5,6        1,2,5,6
2                 hello          2,3,5,6            2,3,5,6
3                 wow            5,6,9,10,13        5,6,9,13
4                 total          1,2,5,6,9,13       1,2,5,6,9,13
```

Comment: Oh what a painful query you have to put together.  If you have only created a junction table, with one row per user id and product, this would be so much simpler.

Comment: I don't think there's a simple way to do this with "pure" sql... Would be easier with a front-end program (java, python, php...)

Comment: I feel this would be a rather convoluted query with the products_id field needing to be taken apart, compared then put back together under the alias of the similarity table. Can your structure not be re created?

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar treating comma separated lists of IDs to emulate bit masks.  Trick is to do a join using like '%,id,% (where id is the key in a table indexed by id). For your case I join table_1 to a table of sequenced integers and the result includes a row for every id in your product_id column.

I do this once for each id you are requesting and join the resulting derived tables to find the common ones.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT p1.id, p1.name name1,p2.name name2, GROUP_CONCAT(p1.N) similarities
FROM (
SELECT *
 FROM table_1 t1
JOIN sequence8 s8 on CONCAT(',',t1.product_ids,',') LIKE CONCAT('%,',s8.N,',%') 

WHERE t1.id =1
) p1
JOIN 
(
SELECT *
 FROM table_1 t1
JOIN sequence8 s8 ON CONCAT(',',t1.product_ids,',') LIKE CONCAT('%,',s8.N,',%') 

WHERE t1.id =4
) p2 ON p2.n = p1.n
GROUP BY p1.id
```